# Interfacing octave with C#

Tags: c#, math, octave

I have developed a program in Octave to which I would like to add a GUI layer. I want to create an executable program in C# that I can distribute but want to stick with the linear algebra constructs of Octave without having to implement them on my own. Particularly, I want basic matrix, vector operations and optimization functions (like `fminunc` and `fmincg`).

What is the best way to achieve this? Appropriate C# linear algebra library, perhaps?

Comment: You should edit your title to match your question, you might get more people interested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are lots of math libraries for c#. [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) seems to be a good free alternative. There are also commercial implementations.

Another alternative is to call Octave with [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) and parse the output. This saves you from rewriting your calculations but you need to able do bundle Octave with your application. If you want to tightly mix c# and math code this will be a quite complicated, but if your math code is a big calculation with a single set of inputs and a single set of outputs it might be a good alternative.

Answer (score 9):

I have written an Octave C# wrapper for my Adastra project:

http://code.google.com/p/adastra/source/browse/trunk/src/Adastra/Tools/OctaveController.cs

This is an example usage: http://code.google.com/p/adastra/source/browse/trunk/src/Adastra/Algorithms/OctaveLogisticRegression.cs This is a hybrid Octave and C# implementation of Logistic Regression classificator.

Comment: @Anton Andreev Can it handle plots?  I can do calculations using OctaveController, but cannot figure out how to view the plots.

Comment: @Anton - this looks awesome; thanks for sharing. Do you know how easy this would be to get working in Mono on Linux? I see you've got some API calls to Kernel32... (UPDATE: I have spotted this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342007/OctaveSharp-Running-GNU-Octave-with-Csharp)

Comment: The API calls are to avoid problems with names on Windows - when you have a space for example. It is not Octave or C# specific. On Linux this would not be needed. The code can be easily adapted to work with Mono, just need to be changed for things like \n\n etc.

Answer (score 3):

To build a standalone:
http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs

I have a similar problem, which is to create a .dll for C#
I've been looking for a way to do this for a while now, I have not been able to find instructions or an easy way to do it. This is more an ongoing project than a question, but I' d definitely take any answer or help!:)

I am planning to keep track of my efforts here, so at the end this should become a page that will allow people to find how to compile octave into a .dll ( always assuming this is possible)

So:

-I am using VS2010

-I started with the MS VS2010 compiled binaries for octave, assuming this will be closer.

-I created a project in VS and used the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;
    char a[900];
    std::cin>>a;
    return 0;
}
```

-The code would of course not find the octave libs, so I added them, e.g.,

```
C:\Octave\Octave-3.6.1-VS10\lib\octave\3.6.1;C:\Octave\Octave-3.6.1-VS10\include\octave-3.6.1;C:\Octave\Octave-3.6.1-VS10\include;$(VCInstallDir)include;...
```

To Include Directories (Right click on Project-->Properties)

Now I get

```
Error   73  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall octave_value::~octave_value(void)" (__imp_??1octave_value@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall octave_value::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_Eoctave_value@@QAEPAXI@Z)    ...\Projects\cppap32\cppap32\main.obj   cppap32
```

which basically means it cannot find octave_value... By using dumpbin.exe we can see that it needs to have both octave.lib AND octinterp.lib

It now does compile.... :)

Next step create a .dll ...

Notes:

To check what is exported by a .lib:

```
dumpbin.exe /exports C:\Octave\Octave-3.6.1-VS10\lib\octave\3.6.1\octave.lib
```

Relevant links:

Similar, open question on other site:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/297336/gnu-octave-for-c-how-to-start

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look the Xoctave. This is an GUI written for Octave. Here is the link: [www.xoctave.com](http://www.xoctave.com)

And maybe the guys there could have a solution for your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed this functionality for my pet-project and all existing solutions weren't user friendly or just didn't work. I created an open-source, cross-platform, .NET Standard library for this sole purpose. I hope it will save some headaches -
[Octave.NET on GitHub](https://github.com/triforcely/Octave.NET)