# Using SWIG to create a C# wrapper for Octave

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, swig, octave

I'm looking at using Octave and its functions in my C# project, but currently the only way to interface C# and Octave is by calling it on the command line and parsing the string output. ([see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026951/interfacing-octave-with-c-sharp)) This is slow (one command line call per script) and error-prone because you have to parse the string.

What if you could wrap Octave in C#, like what EmguCV does for OpenCV, you would get a faster, and neater way to access Octave. [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) is a tool that can generate such a wrapper, but I've no idea if this is possible and to what extent it would work. Do you know how I can get started?

Comment: You could use this http://github.com/apaka/octave-sharp