# Is there a way of using Matlab Image Processing Toolbox in F#?

Tags: .net, r, matlab, f#

I came across this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2012/08/03/access-statistical-packages-from-r-with-f-3-0.aspx) which lets F# use R.
Is anyone aware of a similar way of consuming Matlab libraries in F#? paid as well as free

I could dig up [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2013/07/17/f-type-provider-for-matlab-feedback-requested-contributions-welcome.aspx) which is at github [here](https://github.com/BayardRock/Matlab-Type-Provider).

But it seems this isn't there yet, I specifically want to use Matlab Image Processing toolbox.
I would appreciate if there are any other alternatives for using Matlab Image Processing library in .NET environment as I have some packages written in Matlab that I would like to port to .NET.

Comment: For reference, the matlab type provider is located here: https://github.com/BayardRock/Matlab-Type-Provider

Comment: @Dwin, I have that information already in the question text, and I have mentioned it isn't ready yet, above mentioned github link is included in the blog you mentioned. I have already read that, but I was hoping there are other alternatives I might be missing.

Comment: @DWin I am open to suggestions to make it clearer, but all I really need is a way of porting matlab packages using image processing library to .net environment and F# seems the way to go. Only want to explore if others have attempted it yet.

Comment: I removed my downvote but it still runs the risk of being closed as a request for a package recommendation which is considered off-topic on SO as well. You might want to make more specific what deficiencies you see in the current code and what fixes would be needed to make it acceptable.

Comment: @DWin, the title of that project says "A (not yet complete) F# Type Provider for Matlab" - that could be read that as "this is a work in progress, please don't use"

Answer (score 1):

What about calling MATLAB as an engine?  Here is information on the [MATLAB Engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html).  Basically, with an installation of MATLAB, you can call other MATLAB from other probramming languages.  In the MATLAB help you can find examples of doing this.

Another alternative is to use the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/index.html) from [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). Here is a little more in another Stack Overflow [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026951/interfacing-octave-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Any idea on how does the performance of the engine compare to Java/.NET if not C++?